# Get ONLY the count of members of 'GROUP' type from an AAD group using Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there a Graph API to get the count of members of a specific type from AAD group? For example, consider the following AAD group:

[image]

This group contains 2 members of type 'Group'. Is there a Graph API to get that count (2)? Or should I get all members from the group and do some filtering to get the members of 'Group' type as follows:

```
var groups = new List<Guid>();
var response = await _graphServiceClient
           .Groups[groupId]
           .TransitiveMembers
           .Request()
           .Top(999)
           .GetAsync();

groups.AddRange(ToGroups(response));

private IEnumerable<Guid> ToGroups(IEnumerable<DirectoryObject> members)
{
            foreach (var directoryObj in fromGraph)
            {
                switch (directoryObj)
                {                    
                    case Group group:
                        yield return Guid.Parse(group.Id);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `microsoft.graph.group` type like this

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.group
```

To retrieve the count the query will be

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.group/$count
```

To achieve this in C# I would create request, add casting and count parameter to request URL. Then create http request message and sent this message, read the response and parse the response as integer.

```
var requestUrl = _graphServiceClient.Groups[groupId].TransitiveMembers.Request().RequestUrl;

// add casting and count query
requestUrl = $"{requestUrl}/microsoft.graph.group/$count";

// Create the request message
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
// $count requires header ConsistencyLevel
hrm.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");

// Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
await _graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

// Send the request and get the response.
var response = await _graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);

// read the content and parse it as an integer
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var groupCount = int.Parse(content);
```

Comment: What if I need the count of users? requestUrl = $"{requestUrl}/microsoft.graph.user/$count"; is this the only change required?

Comment: @user989988 Yes, only change is requestUrl = $"{requestUrl}/microsoft.graph.user/$count";

Comment: Thank you! One more question - does the above api return all the users of the group and return the count or return only the count? To be more clear - is the cost associated with the above api v/s https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/id/members the same? in terms of resource units used?